# setting PowerPoint 2010 slide show to HD dimensions

Tags: video, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, screen-capture, high-definition

I am trying to do a screen capture of a PowerPoint 2010 slide show, but I notice that the full screen view of the slide show is closer to a square in shape, with black on both sides of the slide.  This will result in square-ish video which will have black on both sides if it I expanded to full screen.

**So how do I change the dimensions of the PowerPoint 2010 slide show so that it fills the entire screen without any of the unwanted black siding?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo must match slide aspect ratio with screen ratio. Thus, if your screen is 16:9 so does the slide should be. The problem with this is that graphics and images will get stretched. In order to prevent it you must manually **Lock aspect ratio** (right click, **Size and Position**, check the box). You can do this after stretching too, but it requires tweaking the Scale values so that PowerPoint will apply the original aspect ratio. A full tutorial can be found on [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConvertAPowerPointPresentationFrom43RatioTo169WithoutDistortedOrStretchedImages.aspx)'s blog.

I don't use PowerPoint, so I can't tell you exactly, but there should be a slide dimensions and format setting. A [web search](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/13821/change-powerpoint-2010-aspect-ratio/) shows it is in **Design** tab, **Page Setup**.

Mote than that, according to [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-c140551f-cb37-4818-b5d4-3e30815c3e83), PowerPoint 2010 supports video export of slideshow, so I don't know why you would use screen capture.

[image]

Comment: Thank you and +1 for  fast answer.  However, that method stretches the graphics vertically.  It would be nice if the canvas and text were able to change aspect ratio while leaving the embedded graphics in their original aspect ratios.  There must be a way to accomplish this.

Comment: @CodeMed maybe [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConvertAPowerPointPresentationFrom43RatioTo169WithoutDistortedOrStretchedImages.aspx) and [this](http://blog.presentationload.com/tutorial-how-to-display-43-powerpoint-presentations-in-169/) may help.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because the answer is contained in your first link.  However, I am concerned that subsequent readers of this might not get the full solution if the first link changes at some point in the future.

Comment: You would use screen capture to add your voice.

Comment: One approach is to create a new presentation based on the same template but set its slide size to 13.3333 in wide by 7.5 high then copy/paste the content from each of your original slides into the new presentation.  Since the original is 7.5" high (or is by default) the graphics will fill the new slide top to bottom.  Note: if you need to do this routinely, there are a couple of commercial add-ins to automate the whole thing for you.  I have one (Resize at PPTools.com, and there's another at PPTAlchemy.co.uk called Aspects)